# How does @once fare with start_date in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that is to be triggered only once and it keeps on running as a continuous process.

From the airflow docs, it is stated that,

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run
> stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In
> other words, ***the job instance is started once the period it covers has
> ended.***

For my task which always keeps on running when started `@once`, what should be the `start_date`?

I ask this because I do not see the DAG being run at all and the `next-execution` shows as `None`

My job config is as follows:

```
schedule_interval='@once',
start_date=days_ago(2),
catchup=True,
```

I would like my task to be started by the scheduler immediately once and keep it running always.

Answer (score 1):

For **Airflow >= 2.6.0**:

A new scheduling option `@continuous` was added ([issue reference](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/29900))

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='@continuous',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)
```

Note that using `@continuous` will also set `active_runs_limit=1`.

For **Airflow < 2.6.0**:

Use `TriggerDagRunOperator` like:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)

first = Operator()
second = Operator()

last = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='last_task',
    trigger_dag_id='my_dag',
    dag=dag
)

first >> second >> last
```

This will trigger a new dag run as soon as the previous run is completed.

Comment: The reason for doing endless job execution in airflow, as I was told, is to eliminate the operational complexity of onboarding that job as a new service. In my case, the `TriggerDagRunOperator`'s task would not be triggered, because the `first` itself never completes.

Comment: @JavaTechnical I don't think Airflow is the best tool for the `first` task use case.

Comment: I certainly agree with you on that point. In case, if my long-running task fails, then `retries` should take up the role of `TriggerDagRunOperator` here, right?

Comment: retries will start when task is failed.